# how to move uiview from one point ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, rotation

I am creating a app where i want to move uiview from only one side,
I have to change the one point (-y point).

Currently view displayed as

:[image]

But I want this :

[image]

i have tried this :

```
   UIView *viewRed=(UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:11];
    float   angle = M_PI/10;  //rotate 180°, or 1 π radians
   viewRed.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: I have remove labled from rotation view and put them on main view.

Comment: @MidhunMP: Check updated question. and please help me out.

Comment: You can use CAShapeLayer and CATextLayer for doing the same, also please check the CoreText and NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Image with desired shape or draw a layer behind the labels with desired shape

**EDIT:**

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    // Set the starting point of the shape.
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 300)];

// Draw the lines.
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 300.0)];

[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 200.0)];

[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 120.0)];


CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = aPath.CGPath;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Comment: how can i draw layer ? i have use uiview in storyboard.

Comment: thnks but it is not supporting if i change oriantation. :(

Comment: And it is not set to bottom of view? which frame i have to change for set it to bottom of the self.view?

Comment: If you want to support orientation changes, you must remove the layer and should recreate it. Otherwise add image with correct autoresizing

Answer (score 0):

Use CAShapeLayer for achieve this

```
     CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
     CGPathMoveToPoint(path,NULL,0.0,200.0);
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 320.0f, 250.0f);
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 320.0f, 367.0f);
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0.0f, 367.0f);
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0.0f, 200.0f);


     CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
     [shapeLayer setPath:path];
     [shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
     [shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
     [shapeLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 160.0f, 480)];
     [shapeLayer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
     [shapeLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
     [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:shapeLayer];

     CGPathRelease(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create UIViwe class draw shape and add in baseview

```
@interface ShapeView : UIView

@end

@implementation fractalTriangel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
 }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint   (ctx, point1.x,point1.y); 
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, point2.x,point2.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, point3.x,point3.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, point4.x,point4.y);
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1,1, 1, 1);//set color

    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}


@end
```